# Custom Adapter shows error on super()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I am making a custom adapter extending ArrayAdapter. When I extend BaseAdapter, it works fine, but when I use ArrayAdapter, it shows error on super(). My Adapter code:

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private final Context context;
private List<String> Title=new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> Dis=new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> Desc=new ArrayList<String>();
public static  TextView title;
public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<String>title,List<String>dis,List<String> desc) {
    super(); //ERROR HERE

    this.context = context;
    this.Title=title;
    this.Dis=dis;
    this.Desc=desc;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Title.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter,parent, false);
    title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.helloText);
    final TextView dis = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dis);
    final TextView descr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.descr);

    title.setText(Title.get(position));
    dis.setText(Dis.get(position));
    descr.setText(Desc.get(position));

    return v;
}
}
```

And I want to call it as:

```
CustomAdapter ad=new CustomAdapter(this,titles,dis,desc);
```

Where titles, dis,desc are lists.

Comment: where you call your CustomAdapter ( Activity Or Fragment )

Comment: @AhmadAlkhateeb from activity

Comment: Read the base constructors of ArrayAdapters [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at java basics for explanation.
This is an extract:
"You don't have to provide any `constructors` for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default `constructor` for any class without `constructors`. This default `constructor` will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor."

You could read the whole article [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

And further you could take a look at `ArrayAdapter` source as 0X0nosugar suggested.

Comment: can you look here and help me what's wrong with my adapter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013764/swipable-cards-library

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameter to super(), replace **super()** with following

```
super(context,title,dis,desc);
```

Comment: this will not work because there is no constructor for arguments (Context, List, List, List)